# Dynamically JSON Data parse according to index name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How to parse this object data according to index name. I am sharing with you a data example. But in real project am getting huge amount of indexes and children json data too.

Below JSON data example :

```
var vehicles = {
        'cars':[
            {
                "name":"Car 1",
                "model":"Car 1 Model 1"
            },
            {
                "name":"Car 2",
                "model":"Car 2 Model 2"
            },
        ],
        'bikes':[
            {
                "name":"Bike 1",
                "model":"Bike Model 1",
            },
            {
                "name":"Bike 2",
                "model":"Bike Model 2",
            }
        ],
        'buses':[
            {
                "name":"Bus 1",
                "model":"Bus Model 1",
            },
            {
                "name":"Bus 2",
                "model":"Bus Model 2",
            }
        ],
    }
```

Am getting this dynamically from server. In this json packet data cars/bikes/buses. But Can be different names too. 

 Question is how to access Car 1 or Bike 1 according to cars / bikes without define like this below

```
console.log(vehicles.buses[0].name);
Output : Bus 1
```

If you see buses defined here. I want to do this dynamically.
How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question, you want to be able to access each array in the properties without knowing the name of the properties before runtime.

As such you can use the `Object.keys()` collection along with bracket notation to access the array, something like this:

```
Object.keys(vehicles).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(vehicles[key][0].name);
});
```

```js
var vehicles = {
  'cars': [{
    "name": "Car 1",
    "model": "Car 1 Model 1"
  }, {
    "name": "Car 2",
    "model": "Car 2 Model 2"
  }],
  'bikes': [{
    "name": "Bike 1",
    "model": "Bike Model 1",
  }, {
    "name": "Bike 2",
    "model": "Bike Model 2"
  }],
  'buses': [{
    "name": "Bus 1",
    "model": "Bus Model 1"
  }, {
    "name": "Bus 2",
    "model": "Bus Model 2"
  }],
  'foo': [{
    "name": "Foo 1",
    "model": "Foo Model 1"
  }, {
    "name": "Foo 2",
    "model": "Foo Model 2"
  }]
}

Object.keys(vehicles).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(vehicles[key][0].name);
});
```

Comment: exactly what am looking for. @Rory

Answer (score 1):

Create a function where you map the vehicle type array and return the name:

```js
var vehicles = {
  cars: [{
    name: "Car 1",
    model: "Car 1 Model 1"
  }, {
    name: "Car 2",
    model: "Car 2 Model 2"
  }],
  bikes: [{
    name: "Bike 1",
    model: "Bike Model 1"
  }, {
    name: "Bike 2",
    model: "Bike Model 2"
  }],
  buses: [{
    name: "Bus 1",
    model: "Bus Model 1"
  }, {
    name: "Bus 2",
    model: "Bus Model 2"
  }]
};

function getVehicleNames(type) {
  return Object.keys(vehicles[type]).map(key => vehicles[type][key].name)
}

function getAllVehicleNames() {
  return Object.keys(vehicles).map(type => {
      return {[type]: Object.keys(vehicles[type]).map(key => vehicles[type][key].name)}
  })
}

//console.log(getVehicleNames("buses"))
//console.log(getVehicleNames("cars"))
console.log(getAllVehicleNames())
```

Comment: when its dynamically fetch from server and u have no idea its buses or cars then ? @symlink

Comment: @RiponUddin then you'll have to loop through the entire vehicles object.

Comment: i am looking for this @symlink Although Answer no 1 work for me .

Comment: @RiponUddin see my edit

Comment: am getting 72,572 row from server. And it's taking 4-5 minutes to show at DataTable. Is there any way to make it fast ?